# How can I add a target to my button in an extension?

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote an extension to display an empty state if my view controller is empty. I also wanted to add a **UIButton()** with a target. How can I implement the **addTarget** action for my button within the extension? (F.e. a simple "Hello World" or what ever I need)

```
extension UITableView{

    func setEmptyView(title: String, message: String) {

     // handling states

        button.setTitle("+ Add New Documentation", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 24)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor(hex: "BDC86F"), for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: "506182")
       button.addTarget...

    //more code
     emptyView.addSubview(button) 
    }
}
```

Comment: What about adding the param to your method?

Comment: What if you add tableView class as target and write method in your tableView class...so whenever the button will be clicked you will get callback in your VC. With this approach, you will get call-in your VC every time and you can do tasks as per the VC requirements.

Comment: if you like the above idea..I can give you some code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved the same thing for `UIView` extension. Hope, It will help you and I assume that you're able to convert it for `UITableView`

## Code:

```
extension UIView{
    
    func setEmptyView(title: String, message: String) {
        let emptyView = UIView(frame: self.bounds)
        // handling states
        let button = UIButton(frame: emptyView.bounds)
        button.setTitle("+ Add New Documentation", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 24)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTapEvent(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        emptyView.addSubview(button)
        //more code
        self.addSubview(emptyView)
    }
    
    @objc func btnTapEvent(sender:UIButton){
        print("btnTapEvent")
    }
}
```

Reference image:

[image]